# Stylus - reference property from extended selector using property lookup

Tags: css, stylus

I'd like to find a way to reference a property from an extended selector. Unfortunately, [property lookup](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/variables.html#property-lookup) doesn't seem to work for this:

```
.foo
  font-size 12px
.bar
  @extends .foo
  line-height @font-size * 2

/* Output */
.foo,
.bar {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.bar {
  line-height: ;
}
```

This seems like it should be possible. Here's a simple example without `@extends`:

```
.foo
  font-size 12px
  line-height @font-size * 2

/* Output */
.foo {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

Feel free to try this out for yourself: https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html

Comment: The linked page says that you can use variables like so: `font-size: fs =  12px`. Then can't you write `line-height: fs * 2`?

Comment: Seems to produce `line-height: fs` in the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you are neglecting the scope! See commented code below:

```
.foo
  font-size 12px
.bar
  font-size 12px  //<< as long as there is no font-size in .bar scope, you cant reference to it. For that cases use variables.
  @extends .foo
  line-height @font-size * 2 

/* Output */
.foo,
.bar {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.bar {
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

with variables

```
f-size = 12px
.foo
  font-size f-size
.bar
  font-size f-size  
  @extends .foo
  line-height @font-size * 2
  //or
  line-height @f-size * 2
  //or
  line-height f-size * 2


 /* Output */
    .foo,
    .bar {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .bar {
      line-height: 24px;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I've added a ticket on the stylus github page asking about "protected scope" to see if that's something they plan on implementing https://github.com/stylus/stylus/issues/1898